# rosbuild manifest.xml error [SOLVED]

Tags: ros, manifest.xml, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have installed ros fuerte in ubuntu 12.04. Now I am compiling my stuff, but i get this error (in electric+ubuntu10.10 works perfectly):

rosbuild manifest.xml error

[rosbuild] Building package hyselam_topo
[rosbuild] Error from syntax check of hyselam_topo/manifest.xml

My manifest file:

hyselam_topo

fbnsantos
BSD

http://ros.org/wiki/hyselam_topo

Can someone help me on this?

Another related question:

I have tried with  and with  what is the diference here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33055/rosbuild-manifest.xml-error-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SOLVED: The problem was that I have to clean cmakecache.txt and cmakefiles directory!

I have made rm -rf cmakecache.txt cmakefiles. This is the best way to do this?

---

Originally posted by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) with karma: 346 on 2012-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-01**:
The usual procedure is "make clean" or "rosmake --pre-clean".